# Prime number code - please help me in solving this error ('missing if'?)

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  declare
  2  n number;
  3  i number;
  4  counter number;
  5  begin
  6  n:=&n;
  7  i:=1;
  8  counter:=0;
  9  if n=1
 10     then dbms_output.put_line('1 is a prime No.');
 11  else if n=2
 12     then dbms_output.put_line('2 is even prime');
 13  else
 14      for i in 1..n loop
 15     if mod(n,i)=0
 16              then counter:=counter+1;
 17             end if;
 18     end loop;
 19  end if;
 20  if counter=2
 21     then dbms_output.put_line(n||' is a prime No.');
 22  else
 23     dbms_output.put_line(n||' is a not prime No.');
 24  end if;
 25* end
```

I get the following error which I don't understand. Can anyone explain what's causing it?

```
SQL> /
Enter value for n: 8
old   6: n:=&n;
new   6: n:=8;
end
  *
ERROR at line 25:
ORA-06550: line 25, column 3:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the
following:
if
```

Comment: Please explain your question - what do you want your code to do and what isn't it doing?

Comment: Note: 1 is generally not considered prime. See: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeNumber.html. "A prime number ... is a positive integer p > 1 that has no positive integer divisors other than 1 and itself." And "The number 1 is a special case which is considered neither prime nor composite (Wells 1986, p. 31). Although the number 1 used to be considered a prime (Goldbach 1742; Lehmer 1909, 1914; Hardy and Wright 1979, p. 11; Gardner 1984, pp. 86-87; Sloane and Plouffe 1995, p. 33; Hardy 1999, p. 46)."

Answer (score 7):

It's because of this code segment, formatted to give you a better understnding why:

```
 9  if n=1
10  |  then dbms_output.put_line('1 is a prime No.');
11  else
    | if n=2
12  | | then dbms_output.put_line('2 is even prime');
13  | else
14  | | for i in 1..n loop
15  | | | if mod(n,i)=0
16  | | | | then counter:=counter+1;
17  | | | end if;
18  | | end loop;
19  | end if;
    ?
```

In other words, that section is missing an `end if`. That's why, when you finish your file on line 25 with `end`, it complains about not having an `if` after it (to make `end if`).

Just whack an `end if` immediately following line 19 and that should fix it.

---

That should fix your immediate problem but I have a couple of quick comments as well.

- if you use `for i in 2..n loop` (start at 2 instead of 1), and test `counter` being greater than 1 (instead of equal to 2), that should save some work. `mod(n,1)` is zero for *all* `n`.
- in any case, the original test should have been for *greater* than 2, not equal: the number 12 would have given you a `counter` of 5 (one each for 1, 2, 3, 4 and 6) and so would be considered non-prime.
- for efficiency, you should remember that you only ever have to check up to `trunc(sqrt(n))+1` (or the equivalent in whatever language you're using) since, if a number higher than that is a factor, you would have found its pair already: 12 mod 4 is zero but you've already found its pair of 3 (12 mod (12/4) is zero).
- make sure that the `2..n` does not include `n` since the `mod` operation there will also increment counter (I don't know how your specific language handles that loop construct) - it *may* have to be `2..n-1`.

Comment: Helpful, but ultimately misses the syntax error being reported, which is the missing semicolon on line 25. When that error is corrected than the if problem you report is reported. Also, "in any case, the original test should have been for greater than 2, not equal ..." is incorrect. Since the loop is 1..N `mod(n,i)=0` happens twice for prime numbers, once when `i=1` and once when `i=N`. Of course the loop is shortened to only go to square root of N then final test will have to change.

Comment: It's a waste of time checking mod(n,1) since it will always be zero. My point was that it's better to start at 2 and adjust the count check. And the error being reported is _not_ a missing semicolon, it's a unbalanced `if` statement - that's obvious as it states: "expecting one of the following: if", meaning that end has to be an end if. A missing semicolon may well be the next error once you've fixed the reported one but that's not in the question.

Comment: @paxdiablo: Ok, fire up Oracle, balance the if statements without adding a semicolon to the very end and see if it works without returning an error about reaching `end-of-file`.

Comment: "My point was that it's better to start at 2 and adjust the count check." Sorry, I didn't understand that since you said the *original test should* instead of, *after adjusting the the loop the test should be ...*

Comment: @Shannon, I'm not saying that's not a problem. What I'm saying is that it wasn't the problem _being reported_ (as you put it). As shown by the second code sample in your answer, adding the semicolon does _not_ fix the reported error, it just reports it differently, saying it found `;` where an `if` should be, rather than finding `end-of-file` there because, quite simply, you put the `;` before the end of the file :-) You _still_ need to balance the `if`, using either your solution or mine, it doesn't matter in terms of syntax.

Comment: And, for the misunderstanding, since you _know_ mod(x,1) will always be zero, don't { include it then check for a count greater than or equal to 2 }. Instead, { _exclude_ it and check for a count greater than or equal to _1_ }. That saves one wasted modulus operation.

Comment: @paxdiablo: I just took a walk and I think I misspoke earlier. In PL/SQL, an error message that says, "expecting blah" is only right maybe half the time because somewhere else the semantics are off. Almost every time I see "unexpected end-of-file" is when the last end is missing a semicolon. So a good rule of thumb is, when "unexpected end-of-file" is reported, add a semi column at the end and go from there.

Comment: As to optimization, the OP's code needs lots of work. As you state, start from 2 and only go to floor(sqrt(N)) Also, the loop can be exited as soon as a divisor is found, no need to continue. Or being a DB, you could load up a table with primes from a known source, and just search that. :)

Comment: You smile, but the proposal you bring up (and others like it) can be very valid. Cases in point, I often have a table with all the dates a hundred years either side of today so I can join to it in case another table is missing data for that date and I want o reported. I also have an `isPrime` that will pretty well blow away any algorithm you can find (on average) for all the primes under 100 million (since it uses a bit-mask set of files I once created _long_ ago). Bottom line, space/time trade-offs are the bread-and-butter of optimisation :-)

Comment: I smile because just a couple of days ago I was working on a math problem out of a book and got tired of testing whether numbers were prime by hand. I loaded up the first 2,000,000 million primes from http://primes.utm.edu/lists/small/millions/ into a table and then the testing for primes was easy as pi. Almost no coding required.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're looking for the PL/SQL `ELSIF` keyword.  I took your code, replaced

```
else if n=2
```

on line 11 with

```
elsif n=2
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

For every `IF` we should close it by using `END IF;`

But when we use `ELSEIF` one is enough.

```
IF
  ......
  ELSEIF
  ......
END IF;
```

or

```
IF
  ......
   ELSE IF
   .......
   END IF;
END IF;
```

Answer (score 1):

1) You need a semicolon after the final `end` at line 25. 2) Then you get another error, (See note 1 below) and need to correct with by substituting `elsif` for `else if` at line 11. 3) Finaly, 1 not being prime, line 10 needs correction also, `then dbms_output.put_line('1 is neither prime nor composite.);` So the corrected code is:

```
SQL> declare
  2      n number;
  3      i number;
  4      counter number;
  5  begin
  6      n:=&n;
  7      i:=1;
  8      counter:=0;
  9      if n=1
 10          then dbms_output.put_line('1 is neither prime nor composite.');
 11      elsif n=2
 12          then dbms_output.put_line('2 is even prime');
 13      else
 14          for i in 1..n loop
 15              if mod(n,i)=0
 16                  then counter:=counter+1;
 17              end if;
 18          end loop;
 19      end if;
 20      if counter=2
 21          then dbms_output.put_line(n||' is a prime No.');
 22      else
 23          dbms_output.put_line(n||' is a not prime No.');
 24      end if;
 25  end;
 26  /
Enter value for n: 3
old   6:     n:=&n;
new   6:     n:=3;
3 is a prime No.

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Also, see [paxdiablo's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842480/prime-number-code-please-help-me-in-solving-this-error-missing-if/4842525#4842525) answer for additional notes on improving this code with respect to prime numbers.

---

**Note 1:** The second syntax error looks like:

```
SQL> declare
  2      n number;
  3      i number;
  4      counter number;
  5  begin
  6      n:=&n;
  7      i:=1;
  8      counter:=0;
  9      if n=1
 10          then dbms_output.put_line('1 is a prime No.');
 11      else if n=2
 12          then dbms_output.put_line('2 is even prime');
 13      else
 14          for i in 1..n loop
 15              if mod(n,i)=0
 16                  then counter:=counter+1;
 17              end if;
 18          end loop;
 19      end if;
 20      if counter=2
 21          then dbms_output.put_line(n||' is a prime No.');
 22      else
 23          dbms_output.put_line(n||' is a not prime No.');
 24      end if;
 25  end;
 26  /
Enter value for n: 10
old   6:     n:=&n;
new   6:     n:=10;
end;
   *
ERROR at line 25:
ORA-06550: line 25, column 4:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:
if
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE 
   N NUMBER:=&N;
   V_COUNT NUMBER:=0;
BEGIN
  FOR I IN 1..N LOOP
    IF MOD(N,I)=0 THEN
      V_COUNT:=V_COUNT+1;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  IF V_COUNT<=2 THEN
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(N||' ' ||'IS PRIME NUMBER');
   ELSE
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(N||' '||' IS NOT  PRIME NUMBER');
  END IF;  
END;
```

Comment: Too bad you didn't take a moment to explain this

Answer (score 0):

```
declare
  n       number;
  i       number;
  counter number;
begin
  n       := &n;
  i       := 1;
  counter := 0;
  if n = 1 then
    dbms_output.put_line('1 is a prime No.');
  elsif n = 2 then
    dbms_output.put_line('2 is even prime');
  else
    for i in 1 .. n loop
      if mod(n, i) = 0 then
        counter := counter + 1;
      end if;
    end loop;
  end if;

  if counter = 2 then
    dbms_output.put_line(n || ' is a prime No.');
  else
    dbms_output.put_line(n || ' is a not prime No.');
  end if;

end;
```

Answer (score 0):

prime number checking.

```
DECLARE
  N NUMBER :=&N;
  I NUMBER;
  COUNTER NUMBER :=0;
BEGIN
  FOR I IN 1..N LOOP
  IF(MOD(N,I) =0) THEN
  COUNTER :=COUNTER+1;
END IF;
END LOOP;
IF (COUNTER =2) THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(N ||'  '||'IS PRIME NUMBER');
ELSE
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(N ||'  '||'IS NOT A  PRIME NUMBER');
END IF;
END;
```